# How to extract the number of views of a Facebook Video?

Tags: facebook, screen-scraping

I've been trying to build a Facebook Post Scraper with Selenium.
Is there any way to get the number of views of a video?

Comment: Facebook doesn't allow you to scrape them. Use the API.

Comment: Thank you! Using API, Is it possible to extract the number of views of posts when I'm not the uploaded?

Comment: You would have to look the documentation